# I want to send email through zohomail using spring mvc Is this configuration correct for zoho mail to send an email

Tags: java, email, spring-mvc, zoho

This is my bean configuration for sending an email through zohomail

```
  <bean class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
                <property name="host" value="smtp.zoho.com" />
                <property name="port" value="587" />
                <property name="username" value="eamilId" />
                <property name="password" value="password" />
                <property name="javaMailProperties">
                    <props>
                        <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
                        <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                        <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
                    </props>
                </property>
        </bean>
```

While I am running my program I am getting below error

> org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed to close server connection after message failures; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host; nested exception is: java.net.SocketException: Connection closed by remote host. Failed messages: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 553 Relaying disallowed as  ; message exception details (1) are: Failed message 1: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 553 Relaying disallowed as < Zandig@Zandig-PC >

Comment: Have you tried to run your progam with this configuration? what 's the result?are you getting any error/exception?

Comment: yeah i tried,i am getting error like this            org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed to close server connection after message failures; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;
  nested exception is:
 java.net.SocketException: Connection closed by remote host. Failed messages: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 553 Relaying disallowed as <Zandig@Zandig-PC>
; message exception details (1) are:
Failed message 1:
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 553 Relaying disallowed as <Zandig@Zandig-PC>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mention bean id in your bean

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
```

Instead of using

```
<prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
```

change into

```
<prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
<prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback">false</prop>
<prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.port">465</prop>
<prop key="mail.smtp.startssl.enable">true</prop>`
```

Ensure that your from address is also listed in sender list also.

Comment: thank u sir it works , actually i did not add from address

Comment: @bhanupriya I amm having similar problem. Can you elaborate how you solved this ?