# Cannot use Javamail with Zoho

Tags: spring-mvc, jakarta-mail, zoho

Hello i have follow this question:[I want to send email through zohomail using spring mvc Is this configuration correct for zoho mail to send an email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34085695/i-want-to-send-email-through-zohomail-using-spring-mvc-is-this-configuration-cor)

And i have this following configuration bean:

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="smtp.zoho.com"/>
    <property name="port" value="587"/>
    <property name="username" value="info@mywebsite.com"/>
    <property name="password" value="mypassword"/>

    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>

            <prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback">false</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.port">465</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.startssl.enable">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And still i can not send E-mails from my application knowing that my bean was working on my gmail account.
This is the Exception i get:

```
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 553 Relaying disallowed as
```

Comment: [Get rid of the socket factory settings](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes), then enable [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) and make sure you're really authenticating to the server.  If you are, then the server is configured to not let you send mail through it to other systems.

Comment: When i get rid of the socket factory it gives me...com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 Must issue a STARTTLS command first.

Comment: remove the socketfactory class. but keep this  <prop key="mail.smtp.startssl.enable">true</prop>

Comment: When i remove the socketFactory class i get this exception:org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 Must issue a STARTTLS command first.

Comment: As mentioned above, keep the starttls property.  Also, what version of JavaMail are you using?

Comment: I have kept it and still got this Error and my java mail version is 1.4

Comment: I have kept it and still got this Error and my java mail version is 1.4